# How to consume a socket.io WebSocket API in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, websocket, socket.io

I need to consume a third-party WebSocket API in `.NET Core` and `C#`; the WebSocket server is implemented using `socket.io` (using protocol version 0.9), and I am having a hard time understanding how socket.io works... besides that the API requires SSL.

I found out that the HTTP handshake must be initiated via a certain path, which is...

```
socket.io/1/?t=...
```

...whereby the value of the parameter `t` is a Unix-timestamp (in seconds). The service replies with a session-key, timeout information, and a list of supported transport protocols. Due to simplicity, this first request is made via `HttpClient` and does not involve any additional headers.

Next, another HTTP request is required, which should result in an `HTTP 101 Switching Protocol` response. I specified the following headers in accordance to the previous request...

```
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ...
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

...whereby the value of the Key-header is a Base64-encoded GUID-value that the server will use to calculate the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header value. I also precalculate the expected `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header value, for validation...

I tried to make that request using `HttpClient` as well, but that does not seem to work... I actually don´t understand why, because I expect an HTTP response. I also tried to make the request using `TcpClient` by sending a manually prepared GET request over a `SslStream`, which accepts the remote certificate as expected. Sending data seems to work, but there´s no response data... the Read-method returns zero.

What do I miss here? Do I need to setup a listener for the WebSocket connection as well, and if yes how? I don´t want to implement a feature complete socket.io client, I´d just like to keep it as simple as possible to catch some events...

Answer (score 0):

The best way of debugging these issues is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Often connect using an IE and compare IE results with my application and modify my app so it works like the IE.  Using WebClient instead of HttpClient will also work better because the WebClient does more automatically than the HttpClient.

A web connection uses the header of the client and the headers in the server webpage to negotiate a connection mode.  Adding additional headers to you client will change the connection mode.  Cookies are also used to select the connection mode.  Cookies are the results of previous connection to the same server which shortens the negotiations and stores info from previous connection so less data has to be downloaded from server.  The server remembers the cookies.  Cookies have a timeout and is kept until timeout expires. The IE history in your client has a list of IP addresses and Net automatically sends the cookies associated with the server IP.

If a bad connection is made to the server the cookies is also bad so the only was of connection is to remove the cookie.  Usually I go into the IE and delete cookies manually in the IE history.

To check if a response is good the server returns a status.  A completed response contains a status 200 DONE.  You can get status which are errors.  You can also get a 100 Continue which means you need to send another request to get the rest of the webpage.

Http has 1.0 (stream mode) and 1.1 (chunk mode).  Net library doesn't work with chunk.  Chunk requires client to send message to get next chunk and I have not found a way in Net to send the next chunk message.  So if a server responds with a 1.1 then you have to add to your client headers to use 1.0 only.

Http uses TCP as the transport layer.  So in a sniffer you will see TCP and HTTP.  Usually you can filter sniffer just to return Http and look at header for debugging.  Occasionally TCP disconnects and then you have to look at TCP to find why the disconnect occurs.

Comment: All details I already know about the handshake I got from inspecting sessions using Fiddler (there´s a web application that already talks to the socket.io server), but via socket.io javascript client...

Comment: I don't have Wireshark at hand, but Microsoft Message Analyzer will probably do as well, but I am not very familiar with it... do you have a good tutorial about how to inspect a socket communication with such a tool?

Comment: I have also seen some details about the protocol by using Chrome developer tools; and I can see that the browser seems to properly handle the HTTP 101 status... could you make a guess, how it should be implemented using TcpClient?

Comment: I've tried to get http 101 working a lot of times and failed using HttpWebRequest.  Best solution is following :             HttpWebRequest  request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("URL");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;